# Clicking on ads on your own app

Tags: admob

It says in Admob policies and guidelines: *It is against AdMob policy to click on your own live ads. During development and testing, use test ads. If you do need to render live ads before launch, avoid clicking on them. If you click on live ads, your AdMob account may be suspended.*

Does this mean under no circumstance I am not allowed to click on the ads on my app? I get that I´m not allowed to click on them when I am testing the app. But if I download my app from the App Store, and I see an ad that looks interesting, I am not allowed to click on it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not customer support for your favorite company

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely. Avoid clicking on your AdMob ads otherwise you will end up with suspended account and will loose all your hard earned money in your AdMob account. Even do not say to your friends or families to click on your AdMob ads. Google track your ip address, cookies, the area from clicks are comings, frequencies of click per thousand impression and so on. They have rocket science so do not try to do this.

By mistake if you click your ads 4-5 times in a month then it is totally fine. They take serious action when your ads click/views ratio is high.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with these sorts of things is that the company doesn't want you to make money off of yourself, which money is why you are placing ads on your application in the first place.

the specifics you link say "avoid clicking" while also saying "may be suspended."

So if you were to click on your link once, you might be okay, but multiple times in a row and something may happen, more than likely you're suspended.  Accidents happen, but blatantly trying to make money off of the ads and there will be an issue.

---

> But if I download my app from the App Store, and I see an ad that looks interesting, I am not allowed to click on it?

## What I would do

I would contact the company and get their advice.  Ask them specifically

> What should I do if I find an ad I like on my own app, and want to click it.  I don't want to go against the rules, but is there a way to negate the money I would get for that ad, so it doesn't seem like I'm making money off of my own clicks?

This way you can get the company's exact answer, while finding out if there is a way you could click your own ads.

Another way is if you really find something interesting then Google it.  The ad should have information saying what it is, so you should easily be able to find it.  Hopefully you also have some sort of way to check out which ads you are getting, so that in the case of an issue, you can check it out through some sort of log, but maybe not.